# how to send email from php mail function using gmail account?

Tags: php

I have to send email from my gmail account using php mail() function. I have read the phpmailer but I don't want to include any external apis. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `mail()` to send email with your Gmail account, you'll have to use something that talks to [Gmail SMTP server](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287) directly. So you're stuck with writing your own or using one of the availiable libraries, the most commonly known are:

- [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)
- [PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)
- [Zend Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html)

Comment: PHPMailer works well - I implemented code for this last week and it runs very sweet.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming mail() works on your server, just:

```
<?PHP
mail($to,$subj,$body,"From: yourname@gmail.com\r\n");
```

should do it.

The reason this works is that the "From" address on an email is really very much like the return address on a snail-mail envelope.  I can write a letter and mail it from my home, with a return address for my office.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Actually to extend my question, I have to develop a php application which would work on local host and send emails to outside addresses. I guess this is possible only when I use some mail server like gmail, as i dont have access to the client's local server to configure it.

Comment: Most web servers will send mail just fine (to any address in the world).  Have you even tried?  Almost all unix/linux hosts have some variation of sendmail locally, and IIS boxes have some kind of local virtual-smtp service.

Comment: If mail() is *really* broken on your client's server, I'd look at using PHPMailer or SwiftMailer.  These libraries will talk SMTP to a remote SMTP server, with all the options available.  mail() simply can't do that.  But remember: mail() probably works, so try it first, especially if you don't want to rely on a library!